# Backstack messed up after starting browser with startActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

Currently i have this setup:

Activity A is main

Activity A starts Acitivity B

B adds a Fragment to itself:
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new FirstFragment()).commit();`

Then after an interaction, `FirstFragment` is replaced with `SecondFragment` and that is added to the back stack:
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Than if the user clicks on this `Fragment` it starts the browser:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(licenceInfo[2].toString()));
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But after the user returns to my app from the browser with the back button, it is messed up. The `SecondFragment` is [drawn on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19UF7.png) `FirstFragment`. :S If i click back, the `SecondFragment` is no longer drawned on. And lastly, one very annoying thing: when returning to Activity A, its `onCreate` method is called.

If i do not start the browser from `SecondFragment`, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i guess this is a failure of my ROM. I use a custom KitKat ROM, which can work with my old HTC Sensation device. This ROM produces the behavior described above. I just tried with a stock Android 4.2 phone, and 4.4 emulator, and both worked properly...